# Stacking column data in excel SQL query

Tags: sql, excel

I'm trying to pull data from an access database into an excel table with an SQL query. The problem is that my access database has columns with similar data that I want to combine into one single column. This should give me duplicates of the data in other columns for each entry. I'm not great with SQL but I think I have the basics down.

Database structure that I have:

```
Date | Product | Hours 1 | Reason 1 | Hours 2 | Reason 2 |
2019    A          3         "xxx"      5         "yyy"
```

Excel table that I want:

```
Date | Product | Hours | Reason |
2019     A         3      "xxx"      
2019     A         5      "yyy"
```

Also not sure if it's possible but it would be great to see the source column of each

```
Date | Product | Hours | Reason |  Source  |
2019     A         3      "xxx"   "Hours 1"
2019     A         5      "yyy"   "Hours 2"
```

I've tried UNION ALL and got duplicates of the data but not merged into one column. I'm about to try INSERT INTO but sort of lost on how to get each one into the same column

Comment: So before I begin, want to know - is the data only in access? or does your access file have another RDBMS as a back end?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT Date, Product, Hours, Reason, Source
  FROM ( 
SELECT Date, Product, Hours1 Hours, Reason1 Reason, "Hours 1" Source
  FROM Table
UNION
SELECT Date, Product, Hours2, Reason2, "Hours 2"
  FROM Table
)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. It looks like you have a bad data structure in the table. By that I mean its a "flat" table with multiple hours in one row for a record. This is generally a PITA when it comes doing tasks for reviewing data in many to one situations. Normally there would be a table where records get logged separately for each hour involved. I understand you probably didnt build it, but its worth pointing out for you own information.
2. Fundamentally, this issue would be easier to appproach once you understood how that less than desirable structure affects what youre task is. This is essentially, in my mind, a pivot problem. PIVOT in SQL is essentially switching rows and columns. There are may ways to pivot data with code - pick your favorite - most people actually use the function PIVOT, where I tend to teeter between CTE's (common table experessions) and PIVOT. IMO CTE's are easier to read once you understand them. Because Acess SQL doesnt support PIVOT or CTE's we just had to treat the body of what a cte wouldve been as a correlated subquery.

   ```
   SELECT x.* 
   FROM 
   (
       SELECT 
           Date,
           Product,
           Hours,
           Reason,
           [Hours 1] AS Source
       FROM yourTableName
       UNION
       SELECT 
           Date,
           Product,
           Hours,
           Reason,
           [Hours 2] AS Source
       FROM yourTableName
   ) x
   ```